# Is there any way to change the default ethereum template?

Tags: the-graph

I'm here to ask a question about graph-ts.

If this is not the channel, please tell me.

Is there any way to change the default ethereum template?

I want to receive additional miner or nonce values ​​from blockhandler.

[image]